# jquery validate custom method not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to create my own custom method but not sure why its not working, here is the html code

```
<form id="testForm">
    <input type="text" required requnique value="" />
    <input type="button" id="validateIt" value="Run"/>
</form>
```

js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testForm').validate();
    $('#validateIt').click(function(){
        if($('#testForm').valid())
            alert('Valid');
        else
            alert('Not Valid');
    });

});
$.validator.addMethod("requnique", function(value, element) {
    console.log('hhh');
    //some customized test
    return false;
}, "Must be unique.");
```

You can view the working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/TrYfA/

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<input type="text" required requnique value="" />
```

`requnique` is not a known attribute that this plugin will use.  To use or declare a custom rule/method inline, you would place it inside of the `class` attribute, like this...

```
<input type="text" required class="requnique" value="" />
```

You could also put required inside `class` like this...

```
<input type="text" class="requnique required" value="" />
```

This is not mandatory.  Having a `required` attribute is as per HTML5 validation and the the jQuery Validation plugin automatically picks that up along with any other HTML5 validation attributes.

However, my personal preference is to use `required="required"` when I'm using HTML5 validation attributes.  [HTML validity](http://validator.w3.org/) will depend on your `doctype`.

```
<input type="text" required="required" class="requnique" value="" />
```

**IMPORTANT:**

To use the jQuery Validate plugin properly, you **must** have a unique `name` attribute on every input element.  (It's the way this plugin internally keeps track of the form inputs.)

```
<input type="text" name="myname" required="required" class="requnique" value="" />
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/UGLqR/

Comment: `required="required"` is XHTML syntax. In HTML5, you should enter it as a boolean attribute, i.e., `required` ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp))